# Can I back-up to partition to restore my computer to factory settings?

Tags: windows-7, backup, partitioning, formatting, sony-vaio

I have a VAIO model VPC-F11JFX/B. I want to restore it to factory settings (instead of formatting it so I can keep the programs it comes with like VAIO Care). I have like 20 GB of data so I can't copy it into my flash drive and it would take up like 7 of my CD's so I can't do that either. So can I make a new partition (called D) and move the files to D from C. Because I don't know if restoring to factory settings is going to wipe the entire drive or just the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory reset usually wipes all partitions. I would suggest spending some money on a small (500GB) external drive and using that for backups. It's a good idea anyway in future for additional backup down the line.

Comment: is it possible to use windows backup to make a backup file in the partition, so i can transfer that somewhere else later? because it wont let me backup to local disk?

Comment: If you have a second partition, the backup should allow you to save to that partition, yes.